# Microk8s reaches internet but not internal network

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I've just installed `Ubuntu 22.04` on a `vmware` virtual server and started using `microk8s`. The server is part of a local network in which there are some servers, including microsoft `AD` and `IIS` servers that handle the network.

I've `docker` installed on the `ubuntu` system and can run all the containers of the web app with no problem via `docker`. In particular, I have a service (a container) that connects to the windows `AD` server of the local network to authenticate users of the web app. On the host, it works with no problem, can reach the `AD` server and also other servers in the network and do all the necessary operations.

On the other hand, when run on `kubernetes` via `microk8s`, all the services work, they are all reachable from the local network, while at the same time the containers can reach the external network (outside our local network, e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)). Only the internal network seems to be unreachable, for which I always get a timeout error.

##### What I tried (but did not work)

- External service
  [https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors][1]
- Check the dns resolution on the host that gets copied into the container

##### Note

I'm not sure what kind of commands shall be run in order to provide the most useful information about the configuration, so I'll be iterating over this question, extending it with logs and other meaningful information.

Thanks

##### Edit 11/10/2022

I've enable the following addons

```
microk8s is running
high-availability: no
  datastore master nodes: 127.0.0.1:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    dns                  # (core) CoreDNS
    ha-cluster           # (core) Configure high availability on the current node
    helm                 # (core) Helm - the package manager for Kubernetes
    helm3                # (core) Helm 3 - the package manager for Kubernetes
    ingress              # (core) Ingress controller for external access
    metallb              # (core) Loadbalancer for your Kubernetes cluster
```

Another strange thing, is that the containers can access the `postgres` database on the host via the host's ip address (10.1.1.xxx)

##### Edit 2 12/10/2022

Here's the ingress `yaml` file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  selector:
    name: nginx-ingress-microk8s
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
---
#
# Ingress
#
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/erp(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: erp-service
            port:
              number: 8000
      - path: /api/auth(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: auth-service
            port:
              number: 8000
      - path: /()(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ui-service
            port:
              number: 3000
```

I can access the UI and by using the host's `ip` and `/api/auth`, I can access the online documentation of swagger/openapi.
[1]: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

Comment: It could be ingress, enable ingress addon, microk8s enable ingress and enable the ports(tcp ports) on the config map that you want to pass. @lsabi

Comment: I edited my answer. See changes at the end @DBSand

Comment: I would suggest running a simple hello word app to rule any other issues on ur cluster, to check if ingress traffic is being received https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/quick-hello-world-http-deployment-testing-k3s-and-traefik

Comment: Also, when you run docker do you run a ingress container which configures the ports to receive traffic? Microk8s ingres - > routes to your ingress controller in the cluster which will have the ingress rules.

Comment: @DBSand yes, traffic is being received, as I can access swagger/openapi on different services (included the authentication one).
2) I can navigate to the services, but in case I edited my question with the configuration file

Comment: Could you check in Ingress namespace, the nginx-ingress-microk8s-daemonset, check if the ports have been opened, you can open it, this is opened for microk8s ingress which will allow traffic to your controller,  by mentioning the ports: containerPort: 80 hostport: 80 name: http protocol: TCP, similarly for 443.

Comment: Thanks @DBSand for the support, but it seems I'm not the only one struggling with this problem. Could be a bug or some strange configuration due to the virtualization. Anyways, I found a workaround for the moment, so I'll use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this day I haven't managed to find any solution but to circumvent the request and use a "proxy" `endpoint` as suggested in

[Accessing an external InfluxDb Database from a microk8s pod using selectorless service and manual endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833009/accessing-an-external-influxdb-database-from-a-microk8s-pod-using-selectorless-s?rq=1)

Basically, it creates a service with that can be accessed by the cluster and an endpoint that points to the external resource.

##### Actual source config taken from the answer

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: influxdb-service-lb
  #namespace: ingress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.1.2.61
#  selector:
#    app: grafana
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8086
    targetPort: 8086
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: influxdb-service-lb
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.1.2.220
    ports:
      - name: influx
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8086
```

If I'll manage to find a solution, I'll update this answer

Answer (score 0):

I had very same issue on my RHEL mircrok8s cluster. It turned out to be a firewall problem. I can't state the exact ufw commands, but the basic idea might help.

This brought me on the right track:

```
[root@rhel ~]# firewall-cmd --get-log-denied 
filter_FWD_public_REJECT: IN=cali283f04f4612 OUT=cali98ad3013c37 MAC=<something> SRC=10.1.20.17 DST=10.1.20.18 // other details omitted
```

cali283f04f4612 is a Calico interface, used by microk8s.

So I added all cali interfaces to a trusted firewall zone, and the ingress was able to resolve external AND internal addresses:

```
[root@rhel ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface=cali+
success
[root@rhel ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface=cali+ --permanent
success
[root@rhel ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I discovered that it was caused by the fact that microk8s was assigning pods IP addresses from the same CIDR block that my company's network was using.

I changed the CIDR block that microk8s used to issue pod ip addresses using these instructions and it worked:

https://thelinuxnotes.com/index.php/how-to-change-pods-cidr-in-a-microk8s-cluster/